# ruby rails send an email after sign up with devise without confirmable

Tags: ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4, devise-confirmable

i create a sign in /up with devise for my app rails , and i would like just send a email of welcoming but without confirmable or redirecting,

"devise :confirmable, ...

```
has_many :emails
delegate :confirmation_sent_at, :confirmed_at, :confirmation_token, to: :primary_email

def primary_email
  emails.primary || (emails.first if new_record?)
end"
```

i read the documentation of devise but i didn't find ( or understand) my answer.

thx for your help i am new in the community and don't speak english well.

Comment: what error diid you got?

Comment: send mail `after_create :send_welcome_mail` in user model and write code of mail sending in `send_welcome_mail` method of model

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an [after_action](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/after_action) in the model to send an email.

model

```
after_action :send_welcome_email, only: [:sign_up]
```

You will need to create the send_welcome_email yourself. Look up [actionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) which will give you an idea of what you need to do.